# Diffuse boundary condition for fermigas/bosongas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, boundary-conditions, bosons

I'm doing math, usually working only in the classical framework, but my background in quantum physics is close to zero so please forgive me if the question does not make sense.

I was looking into fermigas and gas of bosons. For those models, I've only seen periodic boundary conditions, anti-periodic ones and so on... but always what I would call "deterministic" boundary conditions. For a gas of classical particles, of course, many other boundary conditions, that I will call "stochastic", provide a better description of the model, namely the pure diffuse reflection in which a particle hits the boundary with a certain velocity $v$, and re-enter the gas region with a new velocity $v'$ taken at random. There are other refinement, but let's stay at that level for the moment.

Here are my questions:

- are there example of stochastic boundary conditions for quantum particles ? And if so, any references ?
- if not, can anyone explain quickly why this should not make sense physically ? And maybe point out a reference ?
- I am also wondering about the deterministic boundary conditions: the specular reflection and the bounce-back boundary condition. Aren't photon supposed to encounter specular reflection ?

Any answer to even one of those questions will be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks !